# Which one of these sentences is correct?

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-to-english

For 'I forgot how to swim',will it be:

자는 수영하기 잊었어요.

저는 수영하는 (것을) 잊었어요.

저는 수영하를 잊었어요.

Comment: 저는 수영하는 방법을/어떻게 수영하는 건지 잊었어요/잊어버렸어요.

Comment: All of them are incorrect. Have you ever used a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

저는 수영하는법을 잊었어요. 
어떻게 수영하는지 기억이 안나요.

나는 수영하는법 까먹었어. 
나는 수영하는법 잊어 버렸어.

Comment: Err, I think spacing is incorrect...?